# textview underline not showing on real device

Tags: android, textview, underline

I am using a TextView that uses the following string:
`android:text="@string/menu"`

The string is defined as `<string name="menu"><u>MENU</u></string>` in the `strings.xml` file.

However, the underline only shows in the virtual devices, but not in the preview and more importantly, not in the real device.
What is the issue?

Comment: A bit late, but in my case, removing android:textAllCaps="true" from my TextView solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

or just use this

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() |   Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: This works in the virtual device, but not on my real android phone (which is the same as the virtual device).

Comment: What phone model do you have?

Comment: Pixel (first generation)

Comment: Did you reinstall your application, reset your android studio. Sometimes it don't update properly the apk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UnderlineSpan from SpannableString class for underlining the text :

```
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(<your text>);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
```

Then just use `textView.setText(content);`

### OR

You need to use [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to use HTML in your XML Strings. Simply referencing a String with HTML in your layout XML will not work in a JVM.

SDK < Android Nougat use:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

SDK >= Android Nougat :

```
 myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

To distinguish between Android versions use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N`.

Comment: The problem persists. The underline does not show under the text when the app is ran on the real phone

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: On some devies underlining was working like a charm, but on others (Nokia 10, Alcatel) there was just no underline visible. No matter if using Spannables, Paintflags, Html. I guess this has something to do with the Hardware or the Android version of the provider - whatever, I needed a solution and I came up with the following:

I use a very thin view under the actual text which is just rendering a whitle line. I set its visibility to VIEW.Visible or VIEW.Gone in order to underline or remove the underline. In order to position this view close to the text, I use a constraint layout and constrain it to the bottom, left and right of the view. (But maybe a linear layout works too, vor me, Contraint layout was flexible and I liked that.)

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout          
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/actual_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/underline_hack"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/actual_text"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/actual_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/actual_text"
                android:layout_width = "0dp"
                android:layout_height="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```